# Backpropagation algorithm not converging

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, backpropagation

I am trying to implement a one hidden layer neural net. The weights are getting updated but the predictions are incorrect. I think the values of weights and biases are incorrect but cannot find a solution to the issue.

```
class ShallowNeuralNetwork:
    
    def sigmoid(self, val):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-val))
    
    def sigmoid_derivative(self, val):
        return val *(1 - val)
    
    def __init__(self, hidden_nodes, alpha, epochs):
        #Declaring variables for the constructor call of the shallow neural net class
        #for shallow neural net we only need one hidden layer so we are creating a 2d array to store weights of the hidden layer
        #and output_weights for weights to the single output node
        self.hidden_nodes = hidden_nodes
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.hidden_weights = None
        self.hidden_bias = None
        self.output_weights = None
        self.output_bias = None
                
    def fit(self, X, y):
        #MxN weights where M is the number of input nodes and N is the number of weights each node in N gets m weights
        self.hidden_weights = np.random.rand(X.shape[1], self.hidden_nodes)
        #M biases for the hidden layer
        self.hidden_bias = np.random.rand(self.hidden_nodes)
        #N weights for calculating output
        self.output_weights = np.random.rand(self.hidden_nodes,1)
        #bias value for output 
        self.output_bias = np.random.rand(1)
        
        for _ in range(self.epochs):
            
            for x_one, y_one in zip(X, y):
                Z1 = np.dot(x_one, self.hidden_weights) + self.hidden_bias
                A1 = self.sigmoid(Z1)
                Z2 = np.dot(Z1, self.output_weights) + self.output_bias
                A2 = self.sigmoid(Z2)
                
                error = A2 - y_one
                delta_output_layer = error * self.sigmoid_derivative(A2)
                error_hidden_layer = np.dot(delta_output_layer, self.output_weights.T)
                delta_hidden_layer = error_hidden_layer * self.sigmoid_derivative(A1)

                self.hidden_weights -= self.alpha*delta_hidden_layer
                self.hidden_bias -= self.alpha*np.sum(error_hidden_layer)
                self.output_weights -= self.alpha*delta_output_layer
                self.output_bias -= self.alpha*np.sum(error)

    def predict(self, X):
        Z1 = np.dot(X, self.hidden_weights) + self.hidden_bias
        A1 = self.sigmoid(Z1)
        Z2 = np.dot(Z1, self.output_weights) + self.output_bias
        pred = self.sigmoid(Z2)
        return pred
```

I think I am updating the weights incorrectly , any ideas

Comment: Hmmm, you're going to build from scratch right?

Comment: yes I am building from scratch

Comment: Why are you not adding the bias when you predict?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have added biases to the predict but I still face the same problem

Comment: Can you post the inputs and labels you are using?

Comment: Also, one major change would be your `error` You want to square the value because the way you have it right now, the loss can be negative, meaning even if everything else was working correctly, your network will try to tune the weights so that A2 is as small as possible which is not something you want.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1waFhwC2l8WNjaL8-qcdPilsBsXaEjtv_?usp=share_link -> data used

Comment: There are a few problems with your code however. To name a few: you never calculate the loss of A2 with respect to the error. You also use `Z1` to calculate `Z2` instead of `A1` to calculate it. Also as mentioned before you need to change your error so it can't be negative and update the code to account for that change.